# Is there any good generic JPA DAO implemenation? 

Tags: java, jpa, dao

According [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns), generic JPA DAO(Data Access Object) is a pretty nice pattern.

Is there any good implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a look into the [Spring Data JPA](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/).

A few new concepts were introduced into Spring Data JPA, for instance the Query creation based on the method name, so you can declare a method like `findById(String id)` and the "generic" implementation will interpret the method's name and execute something like `select Entity from Entity where id = 'given string'`

Methods like `findByNameAndLastName(String name, String lastName)` or even `findByNameOrInternalId(String name, int internalId)` are supported too.

Comment: definitely look at this.  I haven't used it but saw a seminar on it, and looked excellent.

Comment: @KevinWelker: the idea is so cool, and if we take a look further is not that complicated, I was surprise that no one thought on that before...

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention a couple more generic dao implementations for JPA:

- Generic DAO toolkit - http://code.google.com/p/generic-dao/
- Related Question in SO -
  [Single DAO & generic CRUD methods (JPA/Hibernate + Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3888575/204788)
- A good blog article on
  JPA DAO -
  http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/09/jpa-implementation-patterns-data-access-objects/

Comment: The blog article is actually the same as the one I linked. :) T

Answer (score 0):

[Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com) supports JPA and has an extensive support for building complex predicates for queries.

It doesn't support updates and inserts but you can use Spring Data for that, as Querydsl also integrates with Spring repositories.