# @EJB Injection fails in a singleton for a bean with no interface view

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

I have a stateless DAO-EJB with a no interface view, which is inherited from a generic abstract DAO class with an additional method `readAll();` So the tree is `FooDAOBean <- extends GenericDAOImpl <- implements GenericDAOInterface`  ([click here to see GenericDAO implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888575/single-dao-generic-crud-methods-jpa-hibernate-spring) - in the link it isn't an abstract class):

```
@Stateless
public class FooDAOBean extends GenericDAOImpl<ENodeFocus, Serializable>{

    @Override   
    public List<Foo> readAll() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

and i have an initialization bean, which should configure the application with some entries:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class InitializationBean {

    @EJB
    FooDAOBean dao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
      // do something
    }
}
```

On deploying i'm getting the errors:

> WFLYNAM0059: Resource lookup for injection failed:
>   env/shitstorm.beans.InitializationBean/dao
>
> WFLYEE0046: Failed to instantiate component view

When i implement a remote interface and annotate `FooDAOBean` with `@Remote(<RemoteInterface>.class)` it is working correctly. But i don't want to allow remote access. For me it is important, that `FooDAOBean`'s methods are only accessible in the same JVM (local). `FooDAOBean` and `InitializationBean` are in the same EAR-Project, so it should be work or do i miss something here? Has it to do with the singleton or whats happening here? Do i have to implement a local interface? I thought since EJB 3.0 i don't need it anymore. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that your `FooDAOBean` is implementing a business interface via its superclass.

The Oracle Java EE tutorial states:

> If the bean class implements a single interface, that interface is
>   assumed to the business interface. The business interface is a local
>   interface unless it is annotated with the javax.ejb.Remote annotation;
>   the javax.ejb.Local annotation is optional in this case.

Thus your `FooDAOBean` actually has a Local interface view instead of the no-interface view which you are expecting.

I would suggest to rename your Bean to sth like `FooDAOBeanImpl`. Then create a interface `FooDAOBean` which inherits from `GenericDAOInterface`. Let your Session Bean `FooDAOBeanImpl` now imeplent the new interface and annotate the class with `@Local(FooDAOBean.class)` to get a clearly defined `@Local` interface view. Now you able to inject `FooDAOBean` as expected.