# @EJB workflowDao is null in service layer

Tags: java, ejb, dao

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a Service/Dao layer in my application.  I've found a few dozen resources all with different ways on how to do it and decided to follow the model found here: [How should EntityManager be used in a nicely decoupled service layer and data access layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856367/how-should-entitymanager-be-used-in-a-nicely-decoupled-service-layer-and-data-ac)

I can't figure out what I'm missing that's causing this NPE.

**Usage:**

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class MyController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String TestRequest() {
        Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
        workflow.setName("test");

        WorkflowService workflowService = new WorkflowService();
        workflowService.save(workflow);

        return "Workflow ID:";
    }
}
```

**My Dao:**

```
@Stateless
public class WorkflowDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        entityManager.persist(workflow);
        return workflow.getId();
    }
}
```

**My Service:**

```
@Stateless
public class WorkflowService {

    @EJB
    WorkflowDao workflowDao;

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        int id = workflowDao.save(workflow); //throws NullPointerException because workflowDao is null
        return id;
    }
}
```

This is my first time setting up a Java project (only have worked on 1 before and it used Spring) so please keep that in mind if this looks horribly wrong.

Comment: Which line is throwing the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorkflowDao` is not an EJB, it's a POJO with a`@Stateless` annotation. So naturally, injecting it with `@EJB` fails, creating a null `workflowDao` attribute and eventually producing a `NullPointerException`.

To make `WorkflowDao` into a full-fledged EJB, besides having a `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` annotation it needs to implement a local, remote or both interfaces, and those interfaces must be annotated respectively with `@Local` and `@Remote`. Please refer to the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnc.html#bnbnd) for details.

Also, quite possibly (this can be application server-dependent) you'll have to register the EJB in the application's xml descriptor files - for instance, in web.xml's `<ejb-local-ref>` element.

As a side note - it's not a good idea to use an EJB as a DAO, an EJB is typically used for implementing business logic (true, persist/merge operations can be called from here) but the actual persistence layer nowadays is implemented using JPA. In other words, `WorkflowService` should be *the* EJB service, there's no need to inject an EJB into it, and there's no need for a separate DAO layer - JPA entities fulfill this role.

Comment: Why is `@Stateless` incorrect?  I frequently see that on DAO objects (http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example/README.html)

Comment: If I don't use EJB, how do I properly make the Dao available to my service?

Comment: @Webnet I clarified my answer. It's not that `@Stateless` is wrong, is that it's not _enough_ : the class needs to implement the local/remote interfaces. If you are not planning to use EJBs, the simply instantiate the DAO in your class, don't inject it - or inject it as a POJO, not as an EJB (depending on the framework you're using). The `@EJB` annotation is reserved for injecting _actual_ EJBs

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate your WorkflowService manually, the container wont perform any injection, since your WorkflowService is not managed by the Container.

I suggest you:

- Annotate your Jax-RS Resource @Stateless
- Inject your WorkfloService via @EJB as a member

Implementing a Local or Remote Interface is not necessary anymore

```
@Path("workflows")
@Stateless
public class WorkFlowResource{
  @EJB
  WorkflowService workflowService;
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String TestRequest() {
    Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
    workflow.setName("test");
    workflowService.save(workflow);
    return "Workflow ID:";
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say `Jax-RS Resource` what are you referring to?  What about how my Dao is linked with the service?  Should that be @EJB or something else?

Comment: I guess your Class that has the 
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

is a JAX-RS Resource

Comment: I added `@EJB WorkflowService workflowService;` to that `MyController` class instead of instantiating it.  It now throws a NPE at `workflowService.save(workflow)`.  I have never used @EJB before so I'm trying to figure this out as I go...

Comment: What is your MyController Class? Do you instantiate it by hand? Like 
new MyController()?

Comment: No, this is a jersey application using grizzly.  I tried the method you showed above, it says `workflowService.save(workflow)` is null.

Comment: Okey, I think your main Problem is, that Grizzly is not an JavaEE ApplicationServer and does not support EJB's, If I remember right, Grizzly is just a Servletcontainer. You should use an Applicationserver for supporting EJB's. Move to Glassfish or try different approach like the Spring-Framework, if you really want to Stick with a plain ServletContainer.