# service layer suggestions

Tags: java, spring, dao

I have some queries regarding the service layers. I have some DAOs called EmployeeDAO,ProjectDAO,etc.
Now which is the best way to access these DAOs? Should I create seperate Service layers for each DAOs or create a common Service layer which will have all the DAOs.
I would like to use spring here.
considering loading the beans and performanche, which is good?

Comment: In my opinion service layer should be as refined as possible which leads to the idea that if the work its performing is not related you should created a separate service class.

Comment: Great discussion related to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882108/dao-and-service-layers-jpa-hibernate-spring

Comment: thanks to @UmeshAwasthi and Andreas_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it would be best if you split things up, for instance `EmployeeService`, `ProjectService`, etc. I think it is better to break things down. Imagine if you have some methods which are common to both, so you use the same method(s) to access both the `Employee` data and the `Project` data. Now, a few months in your project, something changes to the `Employee` data, but not to the `Project` data. You will have to do a refactoring of code which, as far as the `Project` data is concerned, is not needed.

Breaking things down should allow you to maintain the system better.

Comment: @user414967: No problem. Remember that the less you couple classes the better.