# using native query of hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have a query is that , I am using Hibernate and I have to retrieve the records and the query consists of inner join between different tables and
certain conditions as shown below..

```
SELECT ru.* FROM rruser ru
inner join rruser_group rg ON ru.id = rg.user_id
inner join rrgroup_permission rgp ON rg.group_id = rgp.group_id
inner join rrpermission rp ON rgp.permission_id = rp.id WHERE ru.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' AND rp.name='write'
```

Now I want to embed it with hibernate so I want this to be used as native query of hibernate something like this..

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ru.* FROM rruser ru
inner join rruser_group rg ON ru.id = rg.user_id
inner join rrgroup_permission rgp ON rg.group_id = rgp.group_id
inner join rrpermission rp ON rgp.permission_id = rp.id WHERE ru.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' AND rp.name='write'")
List result = query.list();
```

as shown above it will return me an Object array, now please advise can I use it in my other pojos where I need these records which are filtered by above query as I would be requiring thr final records of the query in another pojo and in that pojo how I would call this query please advise

Answer (score 0):

So short answer is you do not put any this kind of code in you pojo, read what is entity bean from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/EJB3_Services-Entity_Beans.html). So your beans can have fields, getters and setters and relationships, that is all. Sample pojo from the link:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {



    String name;

      public String getName () {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      int age;

      public int getAge () {
        return age;
      }

      public void setAge (int age) {
        this.age = age;
      }

      Date signupdate;

      public Date getSignupdate () {
        return signupdate;
      }

      public void setSignupdate (Date signupdate) {
        this.signupdate = signupdate;
      }
    }
```

So where would you want to put that code, so you would want to put it in service layer where it will be transactional. 
Example:

```
    @Transactional
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
        private MyDao myDao;
        private EntityManager em; 

        public List selectSomeData() {
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ru.* FROM rruser ru
inner join rruser_group rg ON ru.id = rg.user_id
inner join rrgroup_permission rgp ON rg.group_id = rgp.group_id
inner join rrpermission rp ON rgp.permission_id = rp.id WHERE ru.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' AND rp.name='write'")
return query.list();
        }
        ...
    }
    }
```

And you will make this bean in application context which will be singleton and everyone uses the instance of it. So whenever you want to call, call from this service.

See this great [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882108/dao-and-service-layers-jpa-hibernate-spring) too