# How to avoid duplicate code when writing various methods in DAOImpl class?

Tags: hibernate, rest, model-view-controller

I have following doubts. Need clarification:
1) I have implemented getEmployee and addEmployee methods in my EmployeeDAOImpl class and both these methods have common code for Hibernate API such as SessionFactory, Session etc . How can I prevent that to avoid duplicacy of code?

2) My Resource class can directly access data from DAO layer then why to go for a service layer?

3) I read somewhere that in MVC architecture one layer should access data only from its immediate next layer e.g. Service layer should access data only from DAO layer. Is this statement true?
Can someone also give me a suitable link or material which provide clear concepts of all MVC related jargons like Business objects, Value object, DTO etc coz I get these doubts quite often.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can abstract the duplicated code into a bean called "BaseDAO"

2.Then UserDAO extends BaseDAO,such as:

```
protected abstract BaseDAO<T>{

    //get Session

    public Integer save(T t) ...
}


public UserDAO extends BaseDAO<User>{

     public void saveUser(User u){
           save(u);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Wrapper class, so only 1 duplicate code line used: session= HibernateUtil.getSession();
   Or use Spring to initialize session/entityManager
2. if you have separate DAO layer it's easier to switch data storage to anything: file backed, key-value database or relational db;

[simple spring app - why use service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688664/simple-spring-app-why-use-service-layer)

[DAO and Service layers (JPA/Hibernate + Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882108/dao-and-service-layers-jpa-hibernate-spring)